# Sass loader not loading style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Webpack is slick... If only I could get it to work. I have two files.

1. App.js
2. App.scss

I want to import the styles from App.scss and use them in App.js

Here is my code.

```
// App.js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import s from './App.scss';


class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={s.app}>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

console.log('what is in s ' + JSON.stringify(s));

export default App;
```

And Sass file.

```
// App.scss
.app {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Console shows that s is an empty object. I would expect to see {app: ...}.

Weback is setup like this.

```
// webpack.config.js

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
       devtool: 'source-map',
       entry: [
           './src/client',
           'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
           'webpack/hot/dev-server'
       ],
       output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      },
      plugins: [
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        })
       ],
       module: {
        loaders: [
        {
             test: /\.scss$/,
             loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
        }, 
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
        }]
       },
       devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true
       }
};
```

No errors from webpack. No errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching I found this [Github issue](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader/issues/206). Solution is to change this line in webpack.config.js

```
loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']
```

to

```
loader: 'style!css?modules!sass'
```